# Using the Outline Operators such as rrcurveto in PostScript

Tags: pdf, fonts, postscript

I know this is probably a quite specific question but I would like to use the rrcurveto Operator in a PostScript File to draw a Font Glyph. I am using ps2pdf as Interpreter (Because I don't get GhostView to run on my M1 Mac) which might make trouble in this case.
Furthermore I can't use for example the hsbw Operator. Do I have to use a certain Dictionary for these Operators?
I would appreciate help a lot!

I tried replacing the Operators, which isn't easy when it comes to rrcurve. I also tried to use the CharStrings Dictionary but I'm not sure wether I implemented it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operator doesn't exist in PostScript, but it is very similar to the `rcurveto` operator. You can write it like this, adding the various vectors together:

```
/rrcurveto { % dx1 dy1 dx2 dy2 dx3 dy3  .  -
  1 dict begin
    {dy3 dx3 dy2 dx2 dy1 dx1}{exch def}forall
    dx1 dy1
    dx1 dx2 add  dy1 dy2 add
    dx1 dx2 dx3 add add  dy1 dy2 dy3 add add
    rcurveto
  end
} def
```

Comment: Thanks! The Problem is, that the Adobe Type-1 Specifications Document actually says these operators exist in PostScript. They are used in the CharStrings Dictionary which specify how Characters in Fonts are being build. However, your code will probably help me because I now can use the operator, thanks.

Comment: Ok. Then they're probably accessible with a special dictionary that can be loaded using `findresource` with the `/ProcSet` category. I'll see if I can find more details.

Comment: Your rrcurveto definition already helped me a lot! But it's actually more of the rcurveto implementation. I just found out that "dx1 dy1 dx2 dy2 dx3 dy3 rrcurveto" is defined by "dx1 dy1 (dx1+dx2) (dy1+dy2) (dx1+dx2+dx3) (dy1+ dy2+dy3) rcurveto". With this definition and your code I already managed to draw a Glyph, but I had to calculate the values by hand, because my PostScript Skills aren't good enough to code a function that transforms the inputs. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I've updated the answer so it should match that definition now. I also changed it to use a style with local variables which should be easier to understand and modify.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the type 1 specification doesn't say that rrcurveto exists in PostScript; it certainly doesn't. It is a CharString Command value, but that's not the same thing at all. And no, the various CharString operations aren't available in PostScript, they are type 1 font operations only. It is conceivable that a PostScript interpreter might implement them in PostScript but most don't, for the very good reason that it would be slow. Note that hsbw is also not a PostScript operator. If you want to use these then you must define a type 1 PostScript font and populate it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, @KenS. I already thought of creating a type-1 font, but it's honestly not quite worth it for me. I managed to draw the Glyph of a Character, which is fine for now :)